# n_jobs parameter for random forest to select all but one/two of the processors

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I would like to set the n_jobs parameter to as close to -1 but not include all processors. If we are using a 16VCPU machine, would this be equivalent to selecting n_jobs to 15? What if we want to select all CPUS but two of the processors? n_jobs = 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-n-jobs:

For `n_jobs` below -1, (`n_cpus + 1 + n_jobs`) are used. For example with `n_jobs=-2`, all CPUs but one are used.

Comment: Thanks dx2-66! So n_jobs = -3 would be all CPUs but two are used?

Comment: Aye, that would be correct.